# How to evaluate the following integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Hope you are doing well and staying healthy during these unprecedented times. I am beginner in Mathematica and I want to do the following integral

```
DSolve[f''[x] == 
  Sqrt (24 hh[x])/(
   aa[x]^3 (bb + Abs[bb - cc] (Cos^2) [(2 Pi [x])/dd]^ee) (kk[x] + 
      2 gg Sin[(2 Pi [x])/dd])), f'[x], x]
```

Comment: Replacing `f'[x]` by `f[x]` in your code, you will obtain `{{f[x] -> 
   C[1] + x C[2] + 
    Inactive[Integrate][
     Inactive[
       Integrate][(24 Sqrt hh[K[1]])/(aa[
          K[1]]^3 (bb + 
           Abs[bb - cc] (Cos^2)[(2 \[Pi][K[1]])/dd]^ee) (kk[K[1]] + 
           2 gg Sin[(2 \[Pi][K[1]])/dd])), {K[1], 1, K[2]}], {K[2], 1,
       x}]`.

Comment: Please describe the problems you are encountering with your code.

Comment: See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)

Answer (score 2):

1. `Sqrt()` => `Sqrt[]`
2. `(Cos^2)[x]` => `Cos[x]^2`
3. `Pi[x]` => `Pi x`

```
DSolve[f'[x] == 
  Sqrt [24 hh[
      x]]/(aa[x]^3 (bb + 
       Abs[bb - cc] (Cos[(2 Pi x )/dd]^2)^ee) (kk[x] + 
       2 gg Sin[(2 Pi x )/dd])), f[x], x]
```

so we get `f[x]->XXX`

Then do a `XXX // Integrate[#, x] &` to get the answer.